# SQL calculated column

Tags: calculated-columns, hana

Here is some example data of my calculated view in SAP HANA. My desired result is the column `*calculated* last teacher`.

| Student ID | Teacher ID | Last Seen | `*Calculated* Last Teacher` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 43 | 20171011 | 27 |
| 1 | 27 | 20171014 | 27 |
| 2 | 51 | 20171010 | 51 |
| 2 | 60 | 20170928 | 51 |

I have 2 students. There is a date when a student has seen a teacher for the last time. For each student I want to calculate the last seen teacher with a SQL statement. Any idea?

Comment: pls. tag DBMS (MySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle, etc) which u r using.

Comment: add some sample data & desired result.

Comment: Lag window function if you're using a dbms that supports it

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, which currently does not support window functions, you could try this:

```
SELECT
    t1.*,
    t3.TeacherID AS last_teacher
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT studentID, MAX(LastSeen) AS max_last_seen
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY studentID
) t2
    ON t1.studentID = t2.studentID
INNER JOIN yourTable t3
    ON t2.studentID     = t3.studentID AND
       t2.max_last_seen = t3.LastSeen;
```

Using window functions we can do away with one of the joins and slightly simplify to the following:

```
SELECT
    t1.StudentID,
    t1.TeacherID,
    t1.LastSeen,
    t2.TeacherID AS last_teacher
FROM
(
    SELECT StudentID, TeacherID, LastSeen,
        MAX(LastSeen) OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID) AS max_last_seen
    FROM yourTable
) t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.StudentID     = t2.StudentID AND
       t1.max_last_seen = t2.LastSeen;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE last_seen IN (
  SELECT Max(last_seen)
  FROM table
  GROUP BY student_id
)
```

Comment: This would return every record, potentially from every student, which happens to have a last seen time which was the max for a given student.  Probably not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Row_Number()` function to get LastRecord by column in `oracle` db like this:

```
Select * from
(
  select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY studentId ORDER BY LastSeen desc) as rn,
    studentId,
    TeacherId
  from yourTable
)
where rn = 1;
```

This function groups every `studentId` and orders rows by `LastSeen` column for every studentIdGroup. Then you can select first row for every group using where statement `where rn = 1`

**UPDATE**
if you want select all rows in your table, then you can join this select satement with your table like this:

```
select * from yourTable t
join 
(
  Select * from
  (
    select 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY studentId ORDER BY LastSeen desc) as rn,
      studentId,
      TeacherId
    from yourTable
  )
  where rn = 1
) s
on t.studentId = s.studentId;
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Thank you for your attention, I updated my answer